# Find $E|f_n-f|^2$. If $K$ continuous and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}K(t)dt=1$ is $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ i.i.d, have distribution $f(x)$. Put $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n K\left(\frac{x-X_k}{h}\right)$ with $n\in \mathbb{N},h>0$ and $K:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, K\geq 0$ measurable. Find $E[f_n(x)], \operatorname{Var}[f_n(x)]$ from $f,n,h$. From this find $E|f_n-f|^2$. If $K$ continuous and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}K(t)dt=1$ is $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ ?

I find $E[f_n(x)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)f(x)dx, \operatorname{Var}f_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-Ef_n)^2f(x)dx$. From this we have $E|f_n-f|^2=\operatorname{Var}|f_n-f|+(E|f_n-f|)^2\to 0, n\to \infty ?$  I don't known it. Look forward to the help.

Comment: 1. The index of summation should be $k$ and $k$ should run from $1$ to $n$, hence we should sum $K(\frac{x-X_k}h)$. 2. The fact that the $X_i$ have the same distribution allows to give a more explicit expression for $Ef_n$, which should be actually $E[f_n(x)]$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you very much. Can you give me a solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you need to show that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ in $L^2$ for each fixed $x$?